# Are anti-neuralyzer eyeglasses normal sunglasses?

Tags: men-in-black

To protect themselves from the neuralyzer, MiB officials wear black eyeglasses.

Are they normal sunglasses? Or, are they some advanced alien gizmos?

Answer (score 8):

The implication (at least if we take the [original script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Men-in-Black.html) at its word) is that a standard pair of Ray-Ban sunglasses should be sufficient.

> Kay draws his neuralyzer. FLASH! Beatrice freezes, staring straight ahead
>   as if hypnotized. Kay takes Jay's glasses off and hands them back to him.
>
> **KAY:** ***Ray Bans***.
>   (pulling off Jay's sunglasses)
>   *Okay, Beatrice. There was no alien, and the flash of light you saw in the sky wasn't a UFO. Swamp gas from a weather balloon was trapped in a thermal pocket and refracted the light from Venus --*